# How to calculate NMF for matrix H from predefined W and V (in W*H ~= V) in python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

I have basis sparse matrix of W and the input matrix of V (in W*H ~= V). If I want to get only H, what is a pythonic way to do this?

Updated: I did it by Nimfa and found it always returns both W and H. I also checked Scikitlearn but still could not find the way to fixed W and V to return only H. May someone specify how to use these packages or other ways to do this?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for reference. I checked it but found only the method that return W (ex. fit_transform()) but could not found how to return H. May you specify some more please?

Answer (score -1):

sklearn.decomposition.NMF

```
components_ : array, [n_components, n_features]
```

Factorization matrix, sometimes called ‘dictionary’.